# How come my list doesn't store all my input?

Tags: c#, list

I want my list to store all the inputs from the split array and still be accessible from outside the for loop. Yet somehow it only stores the first input of that last line.

Example input:

```
"1,2,3"
"4,5,6"
```

Somehow it only stores "4".

Here is my code:

```cs
private static int searchNim(string nim, string filepath)
{
    List<string> fields = new List<string>();
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@filepath);

    for (int x = 0; x < lines.Length; x++)
    {
        fields = new List<string>(lines[x].Split(','));
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < fields.Count; x += 3)
    {
        Debug.Log(fields[x]);

        if (nim == fields[x])
        {
            return x;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Please help me out :(. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `fields = new List<string>(lines[x].Split(','));` try `fields.AddRange(lines[x].Split(','));` Your current code keeps replacing `fields` over and over with the latest split line, rather than adding new elements to its existing content.

Comment: Are you sure you want to read that file every time you call that method? Personally I think I would read it once and store in a class-level field.

Comment: OT in that `ReadAllLines(@filepath);`, you don't need that `@`. It is not a generic "ignore all backslashes" symbol, nor do you need it here

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Well I'm not sure. Is it not the best thing to do especially if the file is edited quite often while the program is running? I am very sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm pretty much a beginner in all this stuff.

Comment: The "best" way to handle a file depends on the exact functionality of your code. If the file contents change often, then you may need to re-read it every time. On the other hand, if that file only changes because of your own code, then use the in-memory version of the contents and possibly keep the file as backup. (writing to and reading from a file is much slower than working in-memory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each iteration of the loop, you overwrite `fields` with a new list. Instead, you could add the values to that list:

```
fields.AddRange(lines[x].Split(','));
```